# How can I create a SQL Query that pulls a flag when the price quantity is 10? I am using Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[FAIL FLAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWuox.png)

What they want is getting the average price from the Price and Price Quantity column (price/pricequantity), and marking the difference. If the price quantity doesn't match all 6 locations, then the flag is a Fail, If the price quantity match all 6 locations, then the flag is a Pass.

[PASS FLAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtVZj.png)

Comment: You need another column for this? Why do you need to store (and maintain) a redundant piece of information that is easily obtained at query time and by definition has to change every time the other column changes?

Comment: If really only those two values should be considered as valid, why not create a check contraint? In general, I think, this kind of data checking should be done by the appilcation and not in the DB

Comment: I need to add the COL "FLAG" and flag when the item number's price quantity is "10". Yes I know that I can do a Where clause to just pull the price quantities of 10, but someone is asking me to make a query that shows a flag alert of "10". I'm not sure why they need a flag column for this information, but they're requesting it.

Comment: Ok, so you want a column in the query, not a column in the table (which is a common request), you should clarify that you just want a _query_ that returns this additional column.

Comment: That helped. I guess it wasn't what they were looking for. If I added something in excel that they are looking for but what a query made out of it in SQL, can I get help with that? I added to my question above

Comment: @nlas: To be fair, we should point out that the already given answer was absolutely correct for your original question. Therefore, you should accept the answer and if you need further assistance, create a new question. Editing the question to a completely other topic after already a correct answer was given is no good idea, no one will understand this later on. Please undo your changes and create a second question. And then please avoid uploading images, they don't help. Please provide sample input data and expected outcome as text, if possible as tables.

Comment: Avoiding "[chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)" and other advice: [How do I ask a good database question?](https://sqlblog.org/ask)

Answer (score 3):

In SQL use CASE WHEN

```
   SELECT *, CASE 
           WHEN PriceQuantity = 10 THEN 'true'
           ELSE 'false'
    END AS Flag
    FROM table
```

Comment: Yes if Flag is a String : we must use 'true' but if flag is bool we can use true

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have `bool`. [Did you try it?](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fff14a1ea044ad3934884150765ea8fb)

Comment: I think this is better to read: SELECT CASE PriceQuantity WHEN 10 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END...But this is of course just my "taste".

Comment: Sorry I misread the ask, you 're right. I use MySQL.

Comment: @Jonas yes but if you ever have to perform any comparison other than `=` (including ranges or checking for NULL), you need to switch to the "harder to read" form anyway.

Comment: Yes, of course. To be clear: I think the answer is fine and correct.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry the question was different.
It is the same method to apply but with the calculation :

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE 
      WHEN ((Price/Qyt) = AVG(Price/Qyt)) THEN 'true'
      ELSE 'false'
    END AS Flag
FROM table
GROUP BY Item, Site, Date, Price, ... (and others column but not Flag)
```

Comment: thank you this worked. if this isn't what the person is looking for or needs additional columns, I will reach back out...thank you all